# mac/linux `dotnet build` The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework.." were not found

Tags: .net, linux, macos, dotnet-cli

When trying to build Microsoft.NET.Sdk style project that targets net47 rather than .netcore or .net std. The `dotnet build` will give an error about missing targeting pack. msbuild will work instead, but i'd prefer to use `dotnet build`. Is there a way.

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
(1179,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework 
".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" were not found. To resolve this, install the
 SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or
 Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the
 Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference 
assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the 
framework you intend.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solution that doesn't require depending on MyGet; adding this props import:

```
   <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
   <OutDir>bin</OutDir>
 </PropertyGroup>
+<Import Project="netfx.props" />
 <ItemGroup>
```

And then include this `netfx.props` file on your solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.  See License.txt in the project root for license information. -->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- When compiling .NET SDK 2.0 projects targeting .NET 4.x on Mono using 'dotnet build' you -->
    <!-- have to teach MSBuild where the Mono copy of the reference asssemblies is -->
    <TargetIsMono Condition="($(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net4')) OR $(TargetFrameworkVersion.StartsWith('v4.'))) AND '$(OS)' == 'Unix'">true</TargetIsMono>

    <!-- Look in the standard install locations -->
    <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND '$(TargetIsMono)' == 'true' AND EXISTS('/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono')">/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>
    <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND '$(TargetIsMono)' == 'true' AND EXISTS('/usr/lib/mono')">/usr/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>
    <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND '$(TargetIsMono)' == 'true' AND EXISTS('/usr/local/lib/mono')">/usr/local/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>

    <!-- If we found Mono reference assemblies, then use them -->
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.5')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.5-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.5.1')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.5.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.5.2')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.5.2-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net46' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.6')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.6-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.6.1')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.6.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.6.2')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.6.2-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net47' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.7-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7.1')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.7.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7.2')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.7.2-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <EnableFrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != ''">true</EnableFrameworkPathOverride>

    <!-- Add the Facades directory.  Not sure how else to do this. Necessary at least for .NET 4.5 -->
    <AssemblySearchPaths Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != ''">$(FrameworkPathOverride)/Facades;$(AssemblySearchPaths)</AssemblySearchPaths>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'== 'net472' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7.2'">
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

(Based on [this](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/91bdb8a8e07f205300d9f7af14969dd9344f6c61/fcs/netfx.props).)

Comment: Firewall is blocking that link. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's possible to pull the targeting package with nuget. And then add a framework path override. Here is a snippet that can be added anywhere to the Microsoft.NET.Sdk .csproj/.fsproj if your target framework is .NET v4.7

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' AND '$(TargetFramework)'== 'net47'">
    <!-- Make .NET 4.7 reference assemblies available even on Linux -->
    <FrameworkPathOverride>$(NuGetPackageRoot)microsoft.targetingpack.netframework.v4.7/1.0.1/lib/net47/</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <!-- Make sure the additional feed is searched. -->
    <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json</RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' AND '$(TargetFramework)'== 'net47'">
      <!-- Make sure the reference assemblies are available -->
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TargetingPack.NETFramework.v4.7"
                        Version="1.0.1" ExcludeAssets="All" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

@knocte answer worked for me, but I had to remove this line.

```
<AssemblySearchPaths Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != ''">$(FrameworkPathOverride)/Facades;$(AssemblySearchPaths)</AssemblySearchPaths>
```

The full text is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.  See License.txt in the project root for license information. -->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- When compiling .NET SDK 2.0 projects targeting .NET 4.x on Mono using 'dotnet build' you -->
    <!-- have to teach MSBuild where the Mono copy of the reference asssemblies is -->
    <TargetIsMono Condition="($(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net4')) OR $(TargetFrameworkVersion.StartsWith('v4.'))) AND '$(OS)' == 'Unix'">true</TargetIsMono>

    <!-- Look in the standard install locations -->
    <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND '$(TargetIsMono)' == 'true' AND EXISTS('/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono')">/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>
    <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND '$(TargetIsMono)' == 'true' AND EXISTS('/usr/lib/mono')">/usr/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>
    <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND '$(TargetIsMono)' == 'true' AND EXISTS('/usr/local/lib/mono')">/usr/local/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>

    <!-- If we found Mono reference assemblies, then use them -->
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.5')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.5-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net451' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.5.1')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.5.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.5.2')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.5.2-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net46' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.6')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.6-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.6.1')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.6.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.6.2')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.6.2-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net47' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.7-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7.1')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.7.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != '' AND ('$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7.2')">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.7.2-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <EnableFrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != ''">true</EnableFrameworkPathOverride>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'== 'net472' OR '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.7.2'">
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I am using MAC OS

Answer (score -1):

Our solution to build .NET Framework 4.7.2 on non Windows

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup> 
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
      <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup> 
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Frameworks" Version="4.7.2" />
  </ItemGroup>  
</Project>
```